# How to use vector functions, instead of FOR loop, in this simple R code?

Tags: r

This is an extension of my similarly-titled question posted yesterday. Yesterday I over-simplified my example, as there are additional variables that drive this amortization example. I´d like to use a vector function instead of a FOR loop in the below R code. Below works fine (I also show the correct output below), but I understand as the model grows the vector functions will prove much faster.

I have an Excel/VBA background, am new to R, and am trying to get my head around R vectors.

Amortization = begin_bal*((1+npr)(1-mpr)(1-co/12)) = end_bal. Fin (yield) below doesn´t figure into ending balances.

Below is the FOR loop code:

```
n_periods <- 8
begin_bal <- 10000
yld <- .20
npr <- .09
mpr <- .10           
co <- .10            

period <- seq(0, n_periods, 1)
fin <- 0
pur <- 0
pmt <- 0
ch_off <- 0
end_bal <- begin_bal

for (i in 1:n_periods) {
  fin[i + 1] <- end_bal[i]*yld / 12
  pur[i + 1] <- end_bal[i]*npr
  pmt[i + 1] <- end_bal[i]*mpr
  ch_off[i + 1] <- end_bal[i]*co / 12
  end_bal[i + 1] <- end_bal[i] + pur[i + 1] - pmt[i + 1] - ch_off[i + 1]
}

amort <- data.frame(period, fin, pur, pmt, ch_off, end_bal)
```

And here´s the (correct) output:

```
print(amort,row.names=FALSE)
 period      fin      pur       pmt   ch_off   end_bal
      0   0.0000   0.0000    0.0000  0.00000 10000.000
      1 166.6667 900.0000 1000.0000 83.33333  9816.667
      2 163.6111 883.5000  981.6667 81.80556  9636.694
      3 160.6116 867.3025  963.6694 80.30579  9460.022
      4 157.6670 851.4020  946.0022 78.83351  9286.588
      5 154.7765 835.7929  928.6588 77.38823  9116.334
      6 151.9389 820.4700  911.6334 75.96945  8949.201
      7 149.1534 805.4281  894.9201 74.57668  8785.132
      8 146.4189 790.6619  878.5132 73.20944  8624.072
```

Comment: I don't think your for loop would work, because you are asking for i+1 where i goes up to 8 and you only want to have 0 though 8.  You could look at something like this to get an idea https://spencerschien.info/post/amortization_calculator/initial_post/creating-amortization-tables-in-r/     this uses  a packagehttps://bookdown.org/jeffreytmonroe/business_analytics_with_r7/finance.html

Comment: the loop works well, but since each iteration depends on the results of the previous one, it is not so simple to convert this loop into i.e. a `apply` family statement. However, to increase the speed, you could initialize your data first, and then pass them as a vector of the right final length. You can avoid that at each iteration of the loop the data is totally copied and rewritten. Just do for example: `fin <-rep(0,length(period))` and the same for the other variable that you initialize just with `0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that difficult, once you'll stop thinking Excel way (I also faced similar problems when I started R 5-6 months back and that's why suggesting you).  You need to convert your logic into a mathematical way only.

- Actually your monthly/periodical `payment` comprises of three items, `pur`, `pmt` and `ch_off` which are dependent of previous balance only.
- Thus, if we calculate `(mpr + co/12 - npr)` for every period our `payment` can be calculated.
- That is further easy as `period` here start from `0` and we can use mathematical formula using `^` to calculate `end_bal` for each `period`.
- Rest of the values are easy to calculate, thereafter.

#### BaseR version

```r
n_periods <- 8
begin_bal <- 10000
yld <- .20
npr <- .09
mpr <- .10           
co <- .10

amort <- data.frame(period = seq(0, n_periods, 1))
amort$end_bal <- begin_bal * (1 - (mpr + co/12 - npr))^amort$period
amort$fin <- c(0, (amort$end_bal * yld/12)[-nrow(amort)])
amort$pur <- c(0, (amort$end_bal * npr)[-nrow(amort)])
amort$pmt <- c(0, (amort$end_bal * mpr)[-nrow(amort)])
amort$ch_off <- c(0, (amort$end_bal * co/12)[-nrow(amort)])

amort
#>   period   end_bal      fin      pur       pmt   ch_off
#> 1      0 10000.000   0.0000   0.0000    0.0000  0.00000
#> 2      1  9816.667 166.6667 900.0000 1000.0000 83.33333
#> 3      2  9636.694 163.6111 883.5000  981.6667 81.80556
#> 4      3  9460.022 160.6116 867.3025  963.6694 80.30579
#> 5      4  9286.588 157.6670 851.4020  946.0022 78.83351
#> 6      5  9116.334 154.7765 835.7929  928.6588 77.38823
#> 7      6  8949.201 151.9389 820.4700  911.6334 75.96945
#> 8      7  8785.132 149.1534 805.4281  894.9201 74.57668
#> 9      8  8624.072 146.4189 790.6619  878.5132 73.20944
```

---

#### dplyr version

```r
n_periods <- 8
begin_bal <- 10000
yld <- .20
npr <- .09
mpr <- .10           
co <- .10
library(dplyr)

seq(0, n_periods, 1) %>% as.data.frame() %>%
  setNames('period') %>%
  mutate(end_bal = begin_bal * (1 - (mpr + co/12 - npr))^period,
         payment = -1 * c(0, diff(end_bal)),
         fin = c(0, (end_bal * yld/12)[-nrow(.)]),
         pur = c(0, (end_bal * npr)[-nrow(.)]),
         pmt = c(0, (end_bal * mpr)[-nrow(.)]),
         ch_off = c(0, (end_bal * co/12)[-nrow(.)]))

#>   period   end_bal  payment      fin      pur       pmt   ch_off
#> 1      0 10000.000   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000    0.0000  0.00000
#> 2      1  9816.667 183.3333 166.6667 900.0000 1000.0000 83.33333
#> 3      2  9636.694 179.9722 163.6111 883.5000  981.6667 81.80556
#> 4      3  9460.022 176.6727 160.6116 867.3025  963.6694 80.30579
#> 5      4  9286.588 173.4337 157.6670 851.4020  946.0022 78.83351
#> 6      5  9116.334 170.2541 154.7765 835.7929  928.6588 77.38823
#> 7      6  8949.201 167.1328 151.9389 820.4700  911.6334 75.96945
#> 8      7  8785.132 164.0687 149.1534 805.4281  894.9201 74.57668
#> 9      8  8624.072 161.0608 146.4189 790.6619  878.5132 73.20944
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

*Note extra column `payment` created can be deleted too*

```
seq(0, n_periods, 1) %>% as.data.frame() %>%
  setNames('period') %>%
  mutate(end_bal = begin_bal * (1 - (mpr + co/12 - npr))^period,
         fin = c(0, (end_bal * yld/12)[-nrow(.)]),
         pur = c(0, (end_bal * npr)[-nrow(.)]),
         pmt = c(0, (end_bal * mpr)[-nrow(.)]),
         ch_off = c(0, (end_bal * co/12)[-nrow(.)]))

  period   end_bal      fin      pur       pmt   ch_off
1      0 10000.000   0.0000   0.0000    0.0000  0.00000
2      1  9816.667 166.6667 900.0000 1000.0000 83.33333
3      2  9636.694 163.6111 883.5000  981.6667 81.80556
4      3  9460.022 160.6116 867.3025  963.6694 80.30579
5      4  9286.588 157.6670 851.4020  946.0022 78.83351
6      5  9116.334 154.7765 835.7929  928.6588 77.38823
7      6  8949.201 151.9389 820.4700  911.6334 75.96945
8      7  8785.132 149.1534 805.4281  894.9201 74.57668
9      8  8624.072 146.4189 790.6619  878.5132 73.20944
```

---

`dplyr::lag` may also be used

```
seq(0, n_periods, 1) %>% as.data.frame() %>%
  setNames('period') %>%
  mutate(end_bal = begin_bal * (1 - (mpr + co/12 - npr))^period,
         fin = lag(end_bal, default = 0) * yld/12,
         pur = lag(end_bal, default = 0) * npr,
         pmt = lag(end_bal, default = 0) * mpr,
         ch_off = lag(end_bal, default = 0) * co/12)
```

Comment: Thank you AnilGoyal! I like the Base R version, it´s very intuitive and easy to follow. I need to study up on vector manipulation, break out of my XLS mindset. Many thanks again

Comment: Its a personal choice.  After learning `tidyverse` I feel it easier.